# Making sure that a returning user gave permission

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a welcome `intent` fulfilment in my web-hook functions, that checks the following condition to welcome a returning user otherwise redirecting them to `ask_for_permission intent`.

```
(conv.user.last.seen && confirmationGranted)
```

The app is storing data on a personal device used by the user, but I do not require the user to sign-in to manipulate it, just give the permission to store locally.

I tested it and it looks like both the `conv.user.last.seen` and `confirmationGranted` objects are somehow saved across conversations, recognising me as a returning user, without me actually persisting it into the user's storage.

**Is it safe to assume that, or do I have to deal with sign-in and persisting the `confirmationGranted` input parameter to recognise that the user of the device has had already previously granted the permission?**

I am seeking advice from someone with more experience in creating Actions on Google.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know that `conv.user.last.seen` **IS** always available except the users first session. So you don't have to store it, unless you need it for some other purpose.

As for the `confirmationGranted`, you should not use it to check whether the user has already granted permission regardless of whether or not it's always available.

BUT I'd strongly recommend storing the **result** of the permission (for example users name) in userStorage and checking whether that information is available about the user. That way, while you still don't need to sign the user in, you can know if a certain information is available to you between conversations.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your insightful answer. I am actually asking the user via firing a `Confirmation` object to get their agreement on storing data on local storage as it is their choice to store personal data. I used it similar to https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#confirmation to check to `confirmationGranted`, but I guess in this case I won't have the permission object filled with anything, right?

Comment: No, but the method I recommend would still be the same. Get the confirmation once and if the user allows storage, set `hasAllowedStorage` in userStorage to true. And check for this value every time you'd like to store data about them. If user denies permission, you won't store this value and it will return false when you check it. **EDIT:** hasAllowedStorage is just a name I made up, you can name it anything you want.